# How to use $.post with button onclick function and not a form?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax

I would like to access my controller on an onclick. The form is postback set for another function. I know how to post if there was a form.  Is there a way to go to the controller without using a form and if so how do I do that?

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("OneMethod", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "formNext" })) { 
<input id="addContent" type="button" onclick="addContent(ind1, ind2)"/>
<% } %>
```

jquery

```
function(addContent(ind1, ind2) {
    //post should go to "TwoMethod" and not "OneMethod" but not sure how...
    $.post($(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize(), function(response) {
        //code
    }, 'json');
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a nice function i wrote to post it from AJAX.

```
submitForm("home/twomethod", $("#formNext"),function(e){do stuff});
```

Which calls:

```
function sumbitForm(url, DetailsForm, SuccessCallBack)
{
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        dataType: "json",
        data: $(DetailsForm).serialize(),
        success: SuccessCallBack,
        error: MyNamespace.handleAjaxError
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm doing the same thing you are...I just get the url from the form instead of hardcoding it. Don't think I deserve a down vote..

Comment: So in this case how would the call know to go to TwoMethod in the controller?

Comment: It gets the URL from your form action attribute, for the twoMethod attribute, youll need to provide your own URL. I have modified the answer.

Comment: +1 for introducing a new way of doing things... I am having trouble with setting up my namespace in this function but I will look into this one definately, thanks

Comment: You can just drop the namespace and create a normal function. I have modified the example to do this.

Answer (score 3):

yes, you simply do:

```
$("#some_ID_To_Button").click(function(){
$.post('/home/myaction', $("#formNext").serialize(), function(response) {
        //code
    }, 'json');
});
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

You cal call $.ajax specifying you are going to POST data.
As you can see the url property is the controller/action and the data is a collection of fields/property you want to send.
I am using JSON here but you can choose a different way.

```
url: '<%=Url.Action("DoSomething", "Home")%>',
data: { Name: $('#Field1').val(), MiddleName: $('#Field2').val(), Surname: $('#Field3').val() },
```

**VIEW**

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <input type="text" id="Field1" name="Field1" value="" /><br />
    <input type="text" id="Field2" name="Field2" value="" /><br />
    <input type="text" id="Field3" name="Field3" value="" /><br />
    <input type="button" id="post_data" name="post_data" value="Save" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('#post_data').click(function() {

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '<%=Url.Action("DoSomething", "Home")%>',
                    data: { Name: $('#Field1').val(), MiddleName: $('#Field2').val(), Surname: $('#Field3').val() },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    beforeSend: function(XMLHttpRequest) {
                        // You can do something before posting data.
                    },
                    complete: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {
                        var Response = $.parseJSON(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
                        if ((XMLHttpRequest.responseText == 'false') || (Response.Status == false)) {
                            // FAIL
                        }
                        else {
                            // SUCCESS
                            alert(Response); // Should be true.
                        }
                    }
                });
            });


        });
    </script>

</asp:Content>
```

My controller returns a boolean but you can change it with an object.

**CONTROLLER:**

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult DoSomething(string Name, string MiddleName, string  Surname)
{
    return (Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet));
}
```